# Postgres: Recreate TRIGGER after replacing function?

Tags: postgresql, trigger

Given a function like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION foo()
RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
BEGIN
    -- do something fancy
END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

which is used in a `TRIGGER`:

```
CREATE TRIGGER bar
    BEFORE INSERT
    ON test
    FOR each ROW
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE foo();
```

Does the `TRIGGER` need to be re-created (DROP + CREATE) if the function *foo()* is changed (using `REPLACE`)?

Was coming across this while reading about [partitioning](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Month_based_partitioning).

Comment: No, you can simply replace the function.  Why not test it yourself?

Comment: I tried, but I got confused by an example that I found somewhere. Can't recollect where I saw it unfortunately. Now I even found it in the official docs: "The trigger definition does not need to be updated, however." [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/ddl-partitioning.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
-- Create the function foo()
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION foo()
RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
BEGIN
    -- do something fancy
    -- You should include the appropriate logic here.
    RETURN NEW; -- For example, return NEW; if it's a row-level trigger.
END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;

-- Create the trigger bar
CREATE TRIGGER bar
    BEFORE INSERT
    ON test
    FOR EACH ROW
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE foo();
```

use the CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION syntax to modify the function foo(), the trigger bar will automatically use the updated function without needing to be re-created (DROP + CREATE). The trigger will automatically reference the latest version of the function definition.